# What is really happenning when GC kicks in the user thread?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

I saw these diagrams like here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx
for a good few years and I thought I understood them.. However when I tried to imagine what is going on in the thread actually I couldnt..

Lets say - when GC runs not on a dedicated thread but in the thread which triggered GC.

Look at the part called "What Happens During a Garbage Collection".

See the red arrow - this supposed to be GC running on the user thread.

So lets say I have a worker method which runs in a thread and that worker runs a loop. And then at some point of time GC kciks in..

my question is - what exactly is going to happen to my thread whem GC start and then finishes.

- **Is there going to be a context switch?**
- **Will be new thread context allocated and new stack loaded for GC to run?**
- **How exactly GC code being executed in someone else's thread** (most puzzling for me)...
  the thread has stack allocated and the code is loaded.. how GC code
  got executed - I cant even begin to imagine this piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does the GC execute on somebody else's thread?  It doesn't, because "your" threads aren't really your threads; they're the CLR's threads!

The CLR can muck around with your thread's stack, not to mention your thread's code, which allows it do something called `thread hijacking`.  Basically, it modifies the return pointer on the call stack so that, once the current method returns, your code is diverted into a special function that allows the garbage collector to run.  Once GC is complete, the program is allowed to return to the appropriate place in your user code, and things continue as normal.

Comment: sounds about right. can you provide with a link to a description of the thread hijacking so i can learn the details. thank you

Comment: Found it in very old Richter's article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx

Comment: Also worth pointing out that CLR thread is not the same as windows thread (as the same CLR thread can be ran on different windows thread at different points in time)